# Registering a network using handler

Tags: java, android

I implemented a class to handle network changes. Here I employed using the handler concept but am getting a null exception when calling the method in **onCreate()** of my service class.(Have checked this code a million times to spot the reason for this exception with no luck). Any pointers fixing this?

Here is how I called the network method to start listening in my **onCreate()** class:

```
if(autoconnect){
   startMonitoringNetwork();
 }
```

Then the called method **startMonitoringNetwork()** code:

```
private void startMonitoringNetwork() {
    if(autoconnect && mConnectivity == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting network listener...");
        try {
       (mConnectivity = new NetworkListener()).registerHandler(NetworkListenerHandler, 0); //Nullpointer at this line.
        mConnectivity.startListening(getApplicationContext());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then the network listener class method to register the handler:

```
public void registerHandler(Handler handler, int value){
    mHandlers.put(handler, value);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

can you tell me when you init the NetworkListenerHandler & mHandlers instance?  The null point exception, always because you call it before them created. You can debug which var is null.